# Spring MVC : Threads not executing in production

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

- I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I want to use
  threads so I can make database transactions, email sending,
  fire-and-forget queries more faster. Unfortunately, they are not
  working on production server. I put a system.out, and it is not
  entering the thread itself. I have thread.start().

  - For application-server, I am using apache-tomcat. I will post the
    server.xml and a place where I was using the thread.
  - One more question. I am issuing thread.start() when I want to start
    the thread. When the task in the thread is complete, does the thread
    automatically die and memory is cleared occupied by that thread?

GroupMemberServiceImpl :

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        if (!(existingMember == null)) {
            if (!(this.groupMembersDAO.checkIfMemberAlreadyExists(existingMember.getUsername(), groupId))) {
                members.setMemberUsername(members.getMemberUsername().toLowerCase());
                members.setMemberactivated(true);
                createToken(existingMember.getFirstName(),members.getMemberUsername(), members.isAccesslevel(), groupId);
                WaitingMembers waitingMembers = new WaitingMembers();
                waitingMembers.setGroupAccountId(groupId);
                waitingMembers.setMemberEmail(members.getMemberUsername());
                waitingMembers.setNickName(nickName);
                this.waitingMembersService.addMemberInWaiting(waitingMembers);

            }
        } else {
            GroupAccount groupAccount = this.groupAccountService.getGroupById(groupId);
            WaitingMembers waitingMembers = new WaitingMembers();
            waitingMembers.setGroupAccountId(groupId);
            waitingMembers.setMemberEmail(members.getMemberUsername());
            waitingMembers.setNickName(nickName);
            this.waitingMembersService.addMemberInWaiting(waitingMembers);
            Person inviter = this.personService.findPersonByUsername(groupAccount.getAdminUsername());
            sendFirstTimeGroupUserAccountActivationEmail(nickName, members, inviter.getFirstName(), groupAccount.getGroupName(), groupId);

        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

Is something wrong with the way that I am using threads? Any sophisticated manner which can prevent the problem?

I am using https, compression and caching on production.

Server.xml on production :

```
 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" compression="force" compressionMinSize="1024" 
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"/>


<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="200" compression="force"
              compressionMinSize="1024" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"  sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="/etc/ssl/private/my-keystore.jks" keystorePass="password" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
/>
```

Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to define ThreadPoolTaskExecutor for the spring. Like this. Take the code snippet from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/). The approach allows to control amount of thread simultaneously working.

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) context.getBean("taskExecutor");

PrintTask2 printTask1 = (PrintTask2) context.getBean("printTask2");
printTask1.setName("Thread 1");
taskExecutor.execute(printTask1);
```

About your second question. Short answer is - yes

Comment: Interesting answer. I can create the bean with this ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, that is no problem, but I don't have class which implements runnable, I just want to execute specific portions of code in threads, nothing more. The one I posted for example. Also, can you please tell me why is thread not working on production?

Comment: All you need is to call you code in the Runnable.run() method. You in fact do this in your lambda function.

Comment: When I use a Runnable.run(),l I am unable to call interface like this.waitingMembersService... I have to use just waitingMemberService. Can you please show me an example how I can execute the code snippet I have in post with TaskExecutor?

Comment: Why **unable to call interface like this.waitingMembersService**?

Comment: I get cannot resolve waitingMemberService. Check the image : http://postimg.org/image/yjyem5e2h/    . Can you give me the code for the TaskExecutor with Lambda?

Comment: You can call GroupServiceMemberImpl.this.waitingMembersService() or call it without **this** at all.

Comment: Ahhh.. Ok, I will do that. I am still waiting for the code. Thanks a lot.